# VB6 Error:Datatype mismatch in the criteria expression SQL

Tags: vb6

i am trying to display records according to the selected day in combo box cmbday on click event.Please help me how to get an interger value, I am getting an ERROR:Datatype mismatch in the criteria expression

```
  Private Sub cmbday_Click()
      Adodc1.RecordSource = "select * from patientEntry where  day=   '" &    cmbDay & "'"
      Adodc1.Refresh
  End Sub
```

Comment: What value is in cmbDay? debug.print it to make sure its correct.  What datatype is the `day` column?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `cmbDay` with `CInt(cmbDay)`

Assuming that you are getting a number value in cmbDay but as a string.

> I tried posting this as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation to post a comment and hence I have posted this as an answer